# How do add better responsive queries in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

What is the better SASS way to write the code below. I end up writing lots of media queries with dimensions and also repeating classes in SASS - surely there is a nice way to use mixins or includes? Anyone else write media queries better than below?

```
$strFullWidth:100%;

.aboutWrapper {
    .logo{width:$strFullWidth;max-width:620px}
}

// MOBILE
@media only screen and (max-width:850px){
    .aboutWrapper {
        .logo{width:$strFullWidth;max-width:420px}
    }
}

// SMALL MOBILE
@media only screen and (max-width:550px){
    .aboutWrapper {
        .logo{width:$strFullWidth;max-width:320px}
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use a aboutWrapper mixin with a width parameter. And I think that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the queries [David Walsh proposes in his blog post](https://davidwalsh.name/write-media-queries-sass). So in your case the mixins could look like:

```
@mixin mobile {
  @media only screen and (max-width:850px) {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin smallMobile {
  @media only screen and (max-width:550px) {
    @content;
  }
}
```

With these mixings, your SCSS code boils down to:

```
$strFullWidth:100%;
.aboutWrapper {
    .logo {
        width:$strFullWidth;
        max-width:620px;
    }
}

@include mobile {
    .aboutWrapper .logo { max-width:420px; }
}
@include smallMobile {
    .aboutWrapper .logo { max-width:320px; }
}
```